# Footer does not appear on the first page of an article

Tags: footnotes, article

The footer appears on all pages except the first one. Here is MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
    \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{I reserve the right to change anything in this document at any time.} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

    \title{Env. Science}
    \author{Syllabus}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \hrule 
    \smallskip
Here is some random text.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You have no footnote in your code. Would you mean `footer`, per chance?

Comment: oops. I am sorry. Yes, I meant footer not footnote.

Comment: Try to insert `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the document class `article`, the first page always has a `plain` style (only page number on the bottom of the page).  The styles of other pages can be specified with the `fancyhdr` package, for example.

If you also want to have the first page in the same style as the others, insert the command `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after the line with `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}         % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{I reserve the right to change anything in this document at any time.}

\title{Env. Science}
\author{Syllabus}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy} % <---
\hrule
\smallskip
Here is some random text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the text in the footer?

Comment: @math, I believe that it is possible, however, so far I didn't doing this :-(. As starting solution can be insert `\textcolor{<desired color> }{ text in the desired color}` into `\fancyfoot`. For this you need to load `xcolor` package. An example of preamble: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\textcolor{blue}{I reserve the right to change anything in this document at any time.}}
`